# Can OCaml be used as a scripting language for C++?

Tags: c++, scripting, ocaml, ffi

I'm interesting in using OCaml as a scripting language for an application written in C++. Similarly to how languages like Lua, Python, or JavaScript can be used.

Is there any library (like there is LuaJIT for Lua, CPython for Python, or V8 for JavaScript) that I can use to run and interace with OCaml?

Comment: You can compile OCaml as a C library and call it from C++

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian That might work if I have to, but if I'd prefer to execute it inside of a VM if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can either embed the toplevel (REPL) in your application, or embed the compiler and dynlink the generated code (this is how [ocaml_plugin](https://github.com/janestreet/ocaml_plugin) works). The toplevel is provided by the compiler-libs library installed with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

there exists [ctypes](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/wiki/ctypes-tutorial) that is meant for integrating C in Ocaml and the reverse.